# Select a value from Drop Down dev Tag

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scalatest, gatling

I need to select a value from a drop down using gatling / scala. code as below. formParam seems not working for this type .can some one help me to solve this issue.i need to select Mobile Phone from the Dropdown.

```
<div id="ext-gen275" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 148px; margin-bottom: 8px; height: 63px;">
    <div class="x-combo-list-item">--Select--</div>
    <div class="x-combo-list-item">Mobile Phone</div>
    <div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Tablet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `formParam` is probably not working because there is no HTML `form` here. You'll need to work out how to pass a suitable command to whatever you are using to make it look like a form control (probably whatever requires the `x-combo-list-` prefix)

Comment: okis.tx for the reply.